# d3.js svg image: scale from center of rectangle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scaling

I'm using d3 to populate a cartesian plane with a bunch of `svg:image` elements spread out over different coordinates.

I'd like to add `mouserover` and `mouseout` logic that zooms the image the mouse is over in and lightens the opacity of the others.  I'm filtering my selection on mouseover to only select the desired element and everything is working great, except my scaling logic doesn't seem to get the desired effect.  The images expand downward and to the right rather than in the outward from the diagonal center.

Here's what I've tried:

1. `transform: scale(1.5)` Which expands, but also totally shifts the image's position
2. `transform: translate(-(width/2), -(height/2))` combined with scale, which does the same but from a different starting position
3. Changing the x and y coords to ones adjusted for half widths and heights, which has the same effect.

Is there no `text-anchor` equivalent for image elements with which I could set an "anchor point" to scale from?  I'm not sure what the html svg parlance is, but I guess I'm thinking of something similar to the anchor points a lot of vector editors have.

Current approach, mouseover handler:

```
  function fade(dir){
    return function(d){
      var others = svg.selectAll("image.movie_cover")
        .filter(function(g,i){
          return g != d
        })
        .transition().duration(800)
        .style("opacity",.3);

      var single = svg.selectAll("image.movie_cover")
        .filter(function(g,i){
          return g === d;
        })
        .transition().duration(900)
        .attr("transform", "translate(-40,-40) scale(1.4)")

        var title = keys[coords.indexOf(d)];
        var url = "/static/eshk/"+hash+"_images/" + title  + ".jpg";

        tt.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
        tt.html(title)  
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
    }
 }
```

Using this method, the images move inconsistent distances despite all being the same size.

Comment: There's no anchor attribute for images. It sounds like you would need a combination of translate and scale; do you have your code somewhere?

Comment: Do the images have different translate/scale values to start with? What's `tt` in your code?

Comment: Sorry, `tt` is just a separate tooltip div.  There are no translations applied to the initial images.  Just x and y coordinates spread out over a cartesian plane using linear scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up: A 50 x 50 box at 200, 200. It needs to transition to a 100 x 100. It is 50 larger and wider, so needs to move back and up 25, eg 175, 175. Replace hard coded values with functions that look up the current width on mouse hover to calculate the exact values.

```
d3.select('svg').append('rect');
rect = d3.select('rect');
rect.attr({
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    color: 'steelblue'
})
.transition()
.attr({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    x: 175,
    y: 175
});
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it's the principle that ended up working.  The real problem is that I wasn't passing my adjusted values through my `x()` and `y()` scaling functions.  Ooops!

Comment: this works if one knows the scale Value but what if one wants to make a dynamic visualization where the scale depends on input data? I'm fighting with that, would be great if someone had some idea...

Answer (score 3):

This could also be done without modifying width or position attributes:

```
                    images.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                    var selection = d3.select(this);
                    var offsetX = parseFloat(selection.attr("x"))+
                                  parseFloat(selection.attr("width")/2.0);
                    var offsetY = parseFloat(selection.attr("y"))+
                                  parseFloat(selection.attr("height")/2.0);
                    selection.attr({
                        transform:"translate("+offsetX+ ","+offsetY+") "+
                                  "scale(1.2) "+
                                  "translate(-"+offsetX+",-"+offsetY+ ")"
                    });
                });
```

And on mouse out, you'd just set the transform to null to remove it.

Basically, this is just translating the center point to the origin, scaling around that, and translating back to the correct position.  Remember that transforms are applied in reverse order (right to left).

I think you were on the right track with the use of translate with scale, but translating back and forth from the origin is what allows it to work while remaining centered at the original location.